# how to use RestMediaTypes.SCHEMA_JSON in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

Can someone let me know how to use `RestMediaTypes.SCHEMA_JSON`?

This is my current controller annotation:

```
@Controller
@ExposesResourceFor(Order.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class OrderController {
}
```

I have added the following in `pom.xml`

> spring-data-rest-webmvc

Comment: I don't understand the question? What is `RestMediaTypes.SCHEMA_JSON`? What are you trying to do? What does not work? What does happen instead?

Comment: Formatted code and keywords.